# DRF: How to auto login with JWT after registration?

Tags: python, authentication, django-rest-framework, registration, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

My models.py:

```
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class UserModel(AbstractUser):

    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Электронная почта',
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    password = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Пароль',
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
    delivery_address = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Адрес доставки',
        max_length=254,
        blank=True,
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Номер телефона',
        max_length=254,
        blank=True,
    )
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        exclude = ('password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff',
                   'groups', 'user_permissions')


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[
                                   UniqueValidator(queryset=UserModel.objects.all().values_list('email'))])
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'password2')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "Пароли не совпадают!"})
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create(email=validated_data['email'],)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

My views.py (As i think, I have to do comething here, but don't exactly what to do):

```
class UserAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Class based view to register user


class RegisterUserAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

my urls.py (toke-urls are from simple-jwt):

```
app_name = 'users'

users_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
users_router.register('users', UserAPIView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(users_router.urls)),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path('register/', RegisterUserAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

I have custom user with email instead of username. JWT with simple-jwt. How to auto login user after registration?

I don't even know where to start from

Comment: what do you mean by auto login?

Comment: Authorization right after registration.

Comment: i think there's no need to authorization after register, but you get authorize when login or access any api

Comment: So, you think that i don't have to change something?

Comment: yes.................